# GLKTextureLoader not loading jpg on "The new iPad"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es, glkit

Im trying to create a cube map of six jpg files from the web in GLKit. It works great on my iPhone 6+ but when i run the same code on "The new iPad" the cube map is just black when applied to an object. If i try the same thing with png files it works. Is there anything specific that needs to be done to load jpg's correctly on certain hardware?

The error from cubeMapWithContentsOfFiles is `nil` so it appears like GLKit thinks it loaded the texture properly.

Here is a demo project http://s.swic.name/Yw8F

Comment: Can you upload your project so that it will save time to create new one

Comment: I uploaded a demo project, see the question please.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions of textures you're generating are themselves determined by the device's display dimensions (e.g. rendering a full-screen UIView to a texture) then the resulting cube-map could easily fall within the `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` on some devices but exceed it on larger devices. What are the pixel dimensions of your cube map on iPhone 6 Plus vs iPad 4th generation? If they exceed 4096 in either dimension you could be in trouble.